# Testing a facebook app on a development server

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The facebook graph API doesn't let you redirect to any address other than the one registered with the app.  So, if you want to test changes to your code on a dev server without deploying it, how would you?  Do you create another facebook app just for testing?

Edit:  This question is about "server flow" authentication.  Ie, when a user signs in, you redirect them to facebook, they sign in, then facebook redirects them back to you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a Facebook Application
2. Then goto *yourapp setting* > In the *Web Site* section: Configure the Site URL, and point it to your Web Server. If you're developing locally, you can use http://localhost:8080/ (or any URL that you're developing on)
3. Don't know if you have to but I also set my Canvas URL under *Facebook Integration* settings.

Reference: Take a look at the **Getting Started** section [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/)

Answer (score 1):

Mac/Linux: Just set your /etc/hosts ie:

```
127.0.0.1   testserver
```

Comment: This is probably the most effective way of doing this. Turn it on to use the testing server, remove it to go back to production.

Comment: I've done this before. It's all fun and games until you forget to change it back later.